# Retaining the original filename for online image search without having own website

Tags: images, filenames, online-storage

Let's say I search online with Google for jpeg images and find that a filename such as ABDCEFG1234567.jpg does **not** appear in the results. I conclude it is unique.

I now wish to save an image file with this name online and tell my friends to search for it.

**The problem**

I don't have my own website and the image-sharing sites I have discovered, change the filename according to their own rules.

**Question**

Can I achieve what I want? Am I missing something absurdly simple?  Do I in fact have to create my own site?

---

Comment: Just give your friends the link the image-sharing site generated. Why do you want them to *search* for the file? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski - Hmm... Maybe you're right - perhaps it is XY. It's part of a lockdown treasure hunt - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/treasure-hunt -  I want the filename to be meaningful (and descriptive of the picture) rather than a semi-random sequence produced by a 3rd party site. I want this filename (chosen by me) to be discoverable by searching online. The correct name can be discovered by rot13 of a different but meaningful-looking name, after which the clue is contained within the picture. As you know some rot13 words are also plaintext words.